# why is that the for loop terminates but the memcpy within copies the same substring?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, substring, memcpy

**My assignment asks us to shorten the words of an user input sentence. Then put the shortened words into a linked list. When the gears of code get stuck: the last word in the sentence gets saved into every node. What repair should be implemented so the code puts a diff word into a node each time.**

**note:** I looked at questions involving memcpy & implemented using 0 and\0 to fill the arrays beforehand. I've also changed the arguments of memcpy with & and without&. I also used memmove and strncpy. This Variation of 'memcpy in for loop to copy substring of array into node' has not been asked.

**Here is my code.** Would appreciate recommendations for learning resources links to c or java in the comments of your answer. As well as suggestions for improving code. Of course if you have a more concise/accurate version of my question I will gladly update it. Thank you!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char *four_letters; 
    struct node *next_node;
}node;

struct node* head= NULL; 

char sentence[120][40]={0}, four_letters[40]={0}; // Tried \0,"0".

int word, num_words=-1; 

void scan(); void print(); void sentence_into_list();

void add(struct node **head, char *four_letters); 

void display(struct node *head);



int main()
{
    scan();
    printf("\n");
    print();
    printf("\n");

    sentence_into_list();
    display(head);
    return 0;
}



void scan()
{
   for(word=0;;word++)
    {
        scanf("%s",sentence[word]);
        num_words++;
        if(getchar()=='\n')
            break;
    }

}

void print()
{
    for(word=0;word<=num_words;word++)
    {
        printf("%s ", sentence[word]);
    }
}

void sentence_into_list()
{   
    for (word=0;word<=num_words;word++)
    {
        memcpy(four_letters, sentence[word], 4);     //tried & //tried strncpy, memmove.
        add(&head, four_letters);
    }
}

void add(struct node **head, char *four_letters)

{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    new_node->four_letters = four_letters;
    new_node->next_node = *head;
    *head=new_node;

}

void display(struct node* head)
{
    struct node *current;
    current = head;
    if(current!=NULL)
    {
        printf("List:");
        do
        {
            printf("%s ",current->four_letters);
            current = current->next_node;
        }

        while(current!=NULL);
            printf("\n");
    }
        else
        {
            printf("empty\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: It's true. Every bug looks different, and no site could hope to be a repository for every possible bug, particularly since most beginner programs have multiple bugs. Debugging is an important skill for a programmer -- perhaps the most important skill -- and it is not achieved by searching the internet for buggy programs with similar symptoms and randomly changing your code based on some imagined pattern. Please read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and try to apply his useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

> the last word in the sentence gets saved into every node. ....

This is happening because `four_letters` pointer of all the nodes of the list are pointing to the same memory location `four_letters` [`char` buffer declared globally - `four_letters[40]={0};`]. Hence, whatever is the last value of `four_letters` will be reflected in all nodes.

**One way of solving this problem is** -
allocate a memory, large enough to hold the data, to the node `four_letters` pointer and copy the content of `four_letters` to it. Alternatively, you can use [**`strdup`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) which does this for you.

So, in the `add()` function, replace this

```
new_node->four_letters = four_letters;
```

with this

```
new_node->four_letters = strdup(four_letters);
```

`strdup` creates a duplicate of the string passed to it. It returns a pointer to newly allocated memory so, you should `free` it  once you are done with it, like this:

```
free (node_ptr->four_letters); //node_ptr is pointer to current node
```

While freeing the dynamically allocated memory of list nodes, make sure to first free the dynamically allocated members of the node structure and then free the node itself.

**The other way of solving this problem is** -
Instead of having a pointer to the `char` in `node` structure, have the `char` array as the member of `node` structure, like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char four_letters[5]; // 5 because it is suppose to keep the four letters only and +1 is for null-terminating character
    struct node *next_node;
}node;
```

and copy the content of `four_letters` passed to `add()` to the structure node member `four_letters`. With this, you don't need to take care of freeing the memory.

**There is one more problem with your code** -
In the function `sentence_into_list()`, you are doing:

```
    memcpy(four_letters, sentence[word], 4);
    add(&head, four_letters);
```

Here you're copying the first `4` characters of `sentence[word]` to `four_letters` but you should also add the null-terminating character at the `5`th location of the buffer `four_letters` before passing it to `add()`, something like this:

```
four_letters[4] = '\0';
```

C language does not have the native string type. In C, strings are actually a one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `\0`.

You are not seeing any problem in your code because you are initializing the buffer with zeros:

```
four_letters[40]={0};
```

and every time you are only copying only the `4` characters to it. So, at the `5`th location you always have `\0`. But assume a case where you are using the buffer for different size of strings. In such case, you must have to place the terminating null-character at the end of the string.

---

**Additional**:

I can see that you are nowhere freeing the memory allocated dynamically for the nodes of the list. Follow the good programming practice, make a habit of freeing the dynamically allocated memory once you are done with it.

Comment: Good job. It's also worth seeing if you can add a link to a duplicate or two. This question has been answered at least 20 times, but, admittedly, it isn't always easy to come up with a duplicate link in short order, or to know if the link you are looking at is the best one to use.